# Convert transparent PNG to JPEG with imagemagick

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, imagemagick

Try to use [imagemagick npm module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/imagemagick).

Need to convert a **.png** file with **transparen**t background to **.jpeg** with **white** background.

Example:

```
const ImageMagick = require('imagemagick');

ImageMagick.convert(
  [
    'source_file.png', 
    'destination_file.jpg'
  ],
  function(err, stdout){}
);
```

The result: destination file is saved with black background.

Didn't find needed option to resolve this issue.

P.S. *For example PHP can do this by using imagecolorallocate() and imagefill() functions.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass arguments in the `convert` function like so:

```
ImageMagick.convert(
  [
    'source_file.png', 
    '-background',
    'rgb(255,255,255)',
    '-flatten',
    'destination_file.jpg'
  ],
  function(err, stdout){}
);
```

Check source here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/imagemagick#convertargs-callbackerr-stdout-stderr

Comment: But it is a pity that there is no detailed description of these arguments

Comment: You can find better description in the original Imagemagick CLI docs

Comment: Do you mean this https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php ?

Comment: Yep that's the one